# Not able to access model in the controller mautic

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, mautic

Not able to access new model in the controller in ***mautic***

Mautic uses **Symfony 2.x** framework

Steps taken:

- created entity extending CommonEntity
- created repository extending CommonRepository
- created model extending FormModel

Registered services in the config

```
'repositories' => [
            'mautic.campaignrequest.repository.campaignrequest' => [
                'class'     => Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::class,
                'factory'   => ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager', 'getRepository'],
                'arguments' => [
                    \Mautic\CampaignRequestBundle\Entity\CampaignRequest::class,
                ],



'models'     => [
            'mautic.campaignrequest.model.campaignrequest'  => [
                'class'       => \Mautic\CampaignRequestBundle\Model\CampaignRequestModel::class,
                'arguments'   => [],
            ],
```

But when tried to access the model in the controller it throws an error saying model is not registered in the container.
Am I missing something??, could someone please help me out.

> The error says:
>
> [2019-12-23 13:23:47] mautic.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   InvalidArgumentException:
>   "mautic.campaignrequest.model.campaignrequest is not a registered
>   container key." at
>   /projects/mautic/2.15.2/mautic/app/bundles/ApiBundle/Controller/CommonApiController.php line 923 {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0):
>   mautic.campaignrequest.model.campaignrequest is not a registered
>   container key. at
>   /projects/mautic/2.15.2/mautic/app/bundles/ApiBundle/Controller/CommonApiController.php:923)"}
>   []

Comment: Did you clear the Mautic cache?

Comment: Yes I tried clearing the cache, but still no luck

Comment: I re-read your code. You cannot add dependencies to repositories. Those classes should only work with database. Models should hold the business logic. It should be the other way around. Repositories should be dependencies of models.

Answer (score 0):

```
'mautic.campaignrequest.model.campaignrequest'  => [
                'class'       => \Mautic\CampaignRequestBundle\Model\CampaignRequestModel::class,
                'arguments'   => [],
            ],
```

You should use **MauticPlugin** instead of Mautic in class as your bundle exist in the plugins folder